# Issue with getters and setters Methods

Tags: java, android, setter, getter, serializable

Hello I am working on the `google NewsReader` Application Using `SAX`, Here I am using `getters` and `setter`s methods for get the data. 
 But I have issue that I could add the value into the `setters` methods but could not get into the `getters` methods, I don't know what's Mistake, Please let me know where I do Mistake .

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

private String title;
private String description;
private String link;
private String date;

public Item() {
    setTitle(null);
    setDescription(null);
    setLink(null);
    setDate(null);
}

public String getTitle() {
    System.out.println(" value of the Gettitle ===============> "+ title);
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    System.out.println("value of the settitle =============>"+this.title);
}
```

---

Output into Logcat:

```
 value of the settitle =============>Oracle CEO Ellison to Buy Most of Hawaiian Island Lanai - Bloomberg

 value of the Gettitle ===============> null
```

---

Here I got the value of `item.getTitle().length()` is null.

Edit:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {

        if(inItem) {
            //System.out.println("value of the content=========>"+content.toString());
            item.setTitle(content.toString());
        } else {
            channel.setTitle(content.toString());
        }
    }
```

---

```
 Item item  = new Item();



        for (int i = 0; i < item.getTitle().length(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("title", item.getTitle().valueOf(i));
            map.put("pubdate", item.getDate().valueOf(i));
            map.put("desc", item.getDescription().valueOf(i));

             items.add(map);

        }
```

Comment: and how do you call getter & setters , post that code please

Comment: inside constructors, you should not call setters & getters or any method if they are overridable.

Comment: can you post assigning value to set method

Comment: I have edited Please check it.

Comment: as per this you will get null pointer exception ..........

Comment: more over valueOf(i) is static function which Returns the string representation of the int argument.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect you've called `getTitle()` on a different instance of `Item` than the one you called `setTitle()` on:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
item1.setTitle("foo");

// Some other code

Item item2 = new Item();
String title = item2.getTitle(); // This will return null
```

Comment: I have same object for both getTitle() and SetTitle().please check my edited code.

Comment: @RahulPatel: No you don't - in the code where you're using `getTitle()`, you've got `Item item = new Item()` just beforehand, just like in my answer.

Comment: check into for loop condition    for (int i = 0; i < item.getTitle().length(); i++)

Comment: @RahulPatel: Yes, that's calling `item.getTitle()` on an item which has just been created, and therefore has no title. In other words, *not* the item which you called `setTitle` on before.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you using 2 different object to `set` and `get`. Check if you are calling the `setter` and `getter` on the same object.

**EDIT**

the object used to set title i.e. `item.setTitle(content.toString());` is not the same as the `item` object created just before the `for` loop. You are recreating/re-initializing the `item` object by using `Item item = new Item()` before the `for` loop. Make a global `item` object and create it only once.

Comment: @iozee I happen to write the answer when @ jon already posted his answer. It does happen. Not a BIG crime I suppose.

Comment: I have same object for both getTitle() and SetTitle().please check my edited code

Comment: What about this line `Item item = new Item()` just above the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

private String title;
private String description;
private String link;
private String date;

public Item() {
    setTitle(null);
    setDescription(null);
    setLink(null);
    setDate(null);
}

public String getTitle() {
    System.out.println(" value of the Gettitle ===============> "+ title);
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    System.out.println("value of the settitle =============>"+this.title);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Item i = new Item();
 i.setTitle("War-Craft");

  i.getTitle();
}
}
```

**Please try to check the instances on which you are setting and getting.**